# Bind boolean values to combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a Combobox and I want to edit a boolean value.

```
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit ItemsSource="{Binding EnumItemsSource}" 
                          DisplayMember="Name"
                          ValueMember="Id"
                          IsTextEditable="False"
                          EditValue="{Binding TargetValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

My ViewModel:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the ItemsSource for Enums
    /// </summary>
    public List<EnumItemObject> EnumItemsSource
    {
        get { return _enumItemsSource; }
        set
        {
            _enumItemsSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

public class EnumItemObject
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And I prepare the data for the Combobox ItemsSource that:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the value to the properties for the BitTemplate view. (similar with EnumTemplate)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyInfo">a boolean property</param>
    private void PrepareDataForBitTemplate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        TargetValue = (int)propertyInfo.GetValue(_firstSelectedItem);
        EnumItemsSource = new List<EnumItemObject>();
        EnumItemsSource.Add(new EnumItemObject() { Id = 0, Name = "Nein" });
        EnumItemsSource.Add(new EnumItemObject() { Id = 1, Name = "Ja" });
    }
```

Is it the approach correct? Any solution easier?

Thanks

Comment: If your code is working, this might be a better question for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Hi Paco, I didn't knowCode Review. Thanks for your tipp. I post it there. Thx

Answer (score 0):

More natural way in WPF is to use a **[Value Converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)**. In short it's an object that manipulates how the values of a property are bound to the UI object.

In your case that means (just for example - there are certainly more approaches) creating a converter which would convert the boolean to `0` or `1` and you can then bind that property to the `SelectedIndex` of a `ComboBox` with pre-defined text Nein/Ja values (on the correct indexes) with that converter.

---

An unrelated thing: if you're developing your app with GUI text in another language than English, I would consider moving it to a resources file with English names for the keys - to make the code more accessible to people not speaking German for example. It may be the case you don't need it, I just felt I should mention it :)